# Passing 2 strings with intent to new activity

Tags: java, string, android-intent

I am so close but can't figure it out. I am trying to pass both Strings movieGroup and movieName to the new activity. The way I have it I can only do one or the other. I would like both to come to a new activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String ID_EXTRA = "com.example.chris.prontopages2.Main22Activity.";
HashMap<String, List<String>> Movies_category;
List<String> Movies_list;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;
MoviesAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    Movies_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
    Movies_list = new ArrayList<String>(Movies_category.keySet());
    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, Movies_category, Movies_list);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            String movieGroup = Movies_list.get(groupPosition);
            String movieName = Movies_category.get(Movies_list.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main22Activity.class);
            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
            i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA ,movieGroup);
            i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA ,movieName);
            startActivity(i);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different keys for `movieGroup` and `movieName`. Something like this,

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA + "movieGroup" ,movieGroup);
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA + "movieName" ,movieName);
```

And in `Main22Activity`, retrieve it like this,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String movieGroup = extras.getString(ID_EXTRA + "movieGroup");
String movieName = extras.getString(ID_EXTRA + "movieName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the extras different names, now the second one is overwriting the first

```
 i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA ,movieGroup);
 i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA ,movieName);
```

Change it to somthing like (or declare separate constants)

```
 i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA + "group" ,movieGroup);
 i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA + "name" ,movieName);
```

and then use those names in the `Main22Activity.class`